# How to remove specific word from image path

Tags: php

Here,I have store image path with **_local**  for identify document but when i display that image path on user side i remove **_local**
Get path in variable like this.

```
$img = MI_local.png
```

I need output like this.

```
$img = MI.png
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simple replace method?

```
echo str_replace("_local", "", "MI_local.png");
```

Output:

```
MI.png
```